# angularJS text tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

I want to create a 'tag' like manipulation system that facilitates working with various tags that contain random content. I have chosen to use angular-ui alert mechanism so I've wrapped it up a bit and got something like this:

a *factory*:

```
app.factory(
        'ObjectTag',
        function () {

            function ObjectTag() {
                this.tags = [];
            }

            ObjectTag.prototype = {
                hasTags: function () {
                    return( this.tags.length != 0);
                },
                addTag: function (msgText, objectId) {
                    this.tags.push({type: 'info', msg: msgText, encapsulatedId: objectId});
                },
                closeTag: function(index){
                    this.tags.splice(index, 1);
                },
                getTags: function () {
                    return this.tags;
                }
            };

            return (ObjectTag);
        });
```

and a *directive*:

```
app.directive('objectTag', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^objectTags',
            template: "<div ng-if='objectTags.hasTags()'><alert ng-repeat='tag in objectTags.getTags()' type='{{ tag.type }}' close='objectTags.closeTag($index)'>{{ tag.msg }}</alert></div>"
        }
    });
```

that I use like this:

```
<object-tag object-tags="objectTags"></object-tag>
```

and also this in my *controller*:

```
$scope.objectTags = new ObjectTag();
```

I want to be able to add and remove tags with ease. 
My problem is that they do not look like I want them to look, I want each tag to float to the right of another and its size to be just enough to hold the text *just like the tags here*, instead each alert tag is shown on a different row.

Comment: Not pertaining to your question, but you may want to use `.service` instead of `.factory` given that you're using `this` and overriding prototypes.

Comment: could you please explain the reason for that

Comment: Sorry I actually misinterpreted your code. I didn't realize you were returning a function not an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this many ways by overriding the Bootstrap CSS. I'm a particular fan of the `display: inline-flex` style. Here is an [example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7VvCw0e2h5yPldInLiv?p=preview). You can read more about it in this [excellent article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) from css-tricks.com.

And the relevant HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-inline" role="alert">Well done!</div>
<div class="alert alert-info alert-inline" role="alert">Heads up!</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-inline" role="alert">Warning!</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-inline" role="alert">Oh snap!</div>

.alert-inline {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: only one tiny issue with that, I want the closing 'x' :D